# Multicolumn extended statistiscs, NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP, CHAR columns, and the bane of my existance

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

This is as a result of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25442/cardinality-is-so-far-off-from-reality).
So I'm working with a query that looks like this:

```
select count(*) 
from table1 
where col1 = 123 
and col2 = '1';
```

The problem is this:  `col2` is defined as a `CHAR(1)` and all sessions set `NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_CI'` and `NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC'` .  (`col1` is a `NUMBER` column.)

First off, without the NLS settings on for the sessions, defining a multicolumn extended stat over `(col1,col2)` works fine and produces appropriate cardinality.

But with `NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_CI'` and `NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC'`, it doesn't use the extended stats.  I believed its much like an index and the NLS settings - we had to define indexes with `(NLSSORT("COL2",'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI'''))` .

So, I implemented a multi column extended stats over `("COL1", (NLSSORT("COL2",'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI'''))` .  But it still doesn't work (but an index defined the same will work).

In the predicate information, it shows that with the NLS settings on, `col2 = '1'` is transformed into:
`NLSSORT(INTERNAL_FUNCTION(col2),'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI''')=HEXTORAW('3100')` .  I believe that the `INTERNAL_FUNCTION()` is due to `col2` being defined as `CHAR(1)`.  I can't change that.

How can I create a multicolumn extended stat column group for these columns given my conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only option here is to 'roll your own' pseudo-multicolumn stats - as extended statistics [cannot be created on Virtual Columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68506). For example:

testbed:

```
drop table table1;
create table table1(col1 integer, col2 char(1));
insert into table1(col1,col2) select mod(level,10), '0' from dual connect by level<=1000;
insert into table1(col1,col2) select mod(level,10)+100, '1' from dual connect by level<=1000;
commit;
select count(*) from table1 where col1=1 and col2='0';
/*
COUNT(*)
--------
     100
*/
```

first try with normal histograms (note 'rows' estimate is 'poor'):

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null,'TABLE1');
explain plan for select * from table1 where col1=1 and col2='0';
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |    50 |   250 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE1 |    50 |   250 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("COL1"=1 AND "COL2"='0')
*/
```

now create virtual concatenated column (note 'rows' estimate is 'good'):

```
alter table table1 add col21 generated always as (col2||col1); 
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null,'TABLE1');
explain plan for select * from table1 where col21='01';
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |   100 |   900 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE1 |   100 |   900 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("COL21"='01')
*/
```

finally repeat with NLS parameters set:

```
alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_CI';
alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';
explain plan for select * from table1 where col21='01';
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |   100 |   900 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE1 |   100 |   900 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter(NLSSORT("COL21",'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI''')=HEXTORAW('303100
              ') )
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

without index:

```
drop table table1;
create table table1(col1 integer, col2 char(1));
insert into table1(col1,col2) select mod(level,10), '0' from dual connect by level<=1000;
insert into table1(col1,col2) select mod(level,10)+100, '1' from dual connect by level<=1000;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null,'TABLE1');
explain plan for select * from table1 where col1=1 and col2='0';
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |    50 |   250 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE1 |    50 |   250 |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COL1"=1 AND "COL2"='0')*/
```

with index:

```
alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_CI';
alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';
create index i_table1 on table1(col1,nlssort("COL2",'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI'''));
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null,'TABLE1');
explain plan for select * from table1 where col1=1 and col2='0';
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |          |   100 |   800 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1   |   100 |   800 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TABLE1 |   100 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("COL1"=1 AND NLSSORT(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("COL2"),'nls_sort=''BINARY_
              CI''')=HEXTORAW('3000') )
*/
```